# How we can insert a horizontal rule/line in google docs using google docs API using PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to insert a horizontal rule in google docs using PHP. I have also followed and gone through this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#inserthorizontalrulechildindex but I am unable to create a horizontal line.
I am trying to send the request with this next approach:

```
 $requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
         'insertHorizontalRule' => [
            'location' => [
               'index' => 1, 
            ],
        ]
    ]),
 ];

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));

$response = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Can anybody tell me what am I missing or what mistake I am making.

getting this error -

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"insertHorizontalRule\" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"fields\" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"insertHorizontalRule\" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"fields\" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so what are they? If not, what do you see?

Comment: I have edited my above question and mentioned the error i am getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to insert a Horizontal Rule with Google Docs API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501947/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-horizontal-rule-with-google-docs-api)

Comment: @Tanaike,i already visited this question you have mentioned but they are not using insertHorizontalRule method. They are creating table to draw a line. and I want to use insertHorizontalRule . Is this possible?